# How to create regex to match a string that contains only hexadecimal numbers and arrows?

Tags: python, regex

I am using a string that uses the following characters:

```
0-9    
a-f    
A-F    
-
>
```

The mixture of the greater than and hyphen must be:

```
->
-->
```

Here is the regex that I have so far:

```
[0-9a-fA-F\-\>]+
```

I tried these others using exclusion with `^` but they didn't work:

```
[^g-zG-Z][0-9a-fA-F\-\>]+
^g-zG-Z[0-9a-fA-F\-\>]+
[0-9a-fA-F\-\>]^g-zG-Z+
[0-9a-fA-F\-\>]+^g-zG-Z
[0-9a-fA-F\-\>]+[^g-zG-Z]
```

Here are some samples:

```
"0912adbd->12d1829-->218990d"
"ab2c8d-->82a921->193acd7"
```

Comment: Should it compulsory contain all of the values you want, or any one also works?

Comment: Also, could you provide some sample inputs and outputs based on your regex.

Comment: It is allowed to contain those it doesn't have to have all of them. But if hyphen or greater then is in there it must be in the format of "->" or "-->"

Comment: Alright, I'll write an answer for this.

Comment: Would this work for you? I'm unsure as I don't know exactly what you want to match... `r"[0-9a-fA-F]+|->|-->"`

Comment: @DanielleM. This only has an issue with the fact I need to exclude g-z and G-Z

Comment: Does your existing regex work? So, you just want to omit `g-z` right?

Comment: I want to be able to use an if statement to falsify the string if it contains `g-z`

Comment: it would use `if regex.match("regex","string"):#If it matches the string but returns false if contains g-z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to escape `-` and `>`
Here's the regex that worked for me:
`^([0-9a-fA-F]*(->)*(-->)*)*$`

Here's an alternative regex:
`^([0-9a-fA-F]*(-+>)*)*$`

What does the regex do?

- `^` matches the beginning of the string and `$` matches the ending.
- `*` matches 0 or more instances of the preceding token
- Created a big `()` capturing group to match any token.
- `[0-9a-fA-F]` matches any character that is in the range.
- `(->)` and `(-->)` match only those given instances.

Putting it into a code:

```
import re
regex = "^([0-9a-fA-F]*(->)*(-->)*)*$"
re.match(re.compile(regex),"0912adbd->12d1829-->218990d")
re.match(re.compile(regex),"ab2c8d-->82a921->193acd7")
re.match(re.compile(regex),"this-failed->so-->bad")
```

You can also convert it into a boolean:

```
print(bool(re.match(re.compile(regex),"0912adbd->12d1829-->218990d")))
print(bool(re.match(re.compile(regex),"ab2c8d-->82a921->193acd7")))
print(bool(re.match(re.compile(regex),"this-failed->so-->bad")))
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
```

I recommend using [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) to check your regex.

Comment: Beware that your regexes let the hexadecimal parts be empty. In the first one, the regex says zero or more one-hyphen arrows, followed by zero or more two-hyphens arrows. The second one says one or any number of arrows with one or more hyphens.

Comment: @Nowhereman you have it wrong. If you find my regex to be incorrect, please cross-check on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) and let me know the test cases. Your suggestion is appreciated, however it is invalid.

Comment: I did, and several bad inputs are accepted: https://regexr.com/74lqq

Answer (score 2):

If there must be an arrow present, and not at the start or end of the string using a case insensitive pattern:

```
^[a-f\d]+(?:-{1,2}>[a-f\d]+)+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-f\d]+` Match 1+ chars a-f or digits
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `-{1,2}>[a-f\d]+` Match `-` or `--` and `>` followed by 1+ chars a-f or digits
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e8rsyy/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QZh06g).

```
import re

pattern = r"^[a-f\d]+(?:-{1,2}>[a-f\d]+)+$"
s = ("0912adbd->12d1829-->218990d\n"
            "ab2c8d-->82a921->193acd7\n"
            "test")
print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.I | re.M))
```

Output

```
[
  '0912adbd->12d1829-->218990d',
  'ab2c8d-->82a921->193acd7'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the regex by steps. If I understand your requirements, you want a sequence of hexadecimal numbers (like `a01d` or `11efeb23`, separated by arrows with one or two hyphens (`->` or `-->`).

The hex part's regex is `[0-9a-fA-F]+` (assuming it cannot be empty).

The arrow's regex can be `-{1,2}>` or (->|-->).

The arrow is only needed before each hex number but the first, so you'll build the final regex in two parts: the first number, then the repetition of arrow and number.

So the general structure will be:

```
NUMBER(ARROW NUMBER)*
```

Which gives the following regex:

```
[0-9a-fA-F]+(-{1,2}>[0-9a-fA-F]+)*
```